# Injecting dependencies with runtime dependencies

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I'm building an application that performs actions initiated by a user and one particular class has dependencies on things I can wire up in DI such as an `ILogger` instance as well as an `HttpClient` in addition to runtime arguments that identify the user and the instance of the action (mostly to be used while logging to help with debugging).

The trouble I have is that I'm not entirely sure how to inject this class into the other classes that need it as a result of the runtime dependencies.

Here's a simplified example of one of my classes:

```cs
public class Dependency : IDependency
{
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient;
    private readonly ILogger<Dependency> logger;
    private readonly RuntimeDeps runtimeDeps
    public Dependency(
        ILogger<Dependency> logger,
        HttpClient httpClient,
        RuntimeDeps runtimeDeps)
    {
       // set private fields
    }

    public Result DoStuff()
    {
        // use Http client to talk to external API
        // something fails so log the failure and some helpful info
        logger.log($"{runtimeDeps.InstanceId} failed. " +
            "Initiated by {runtimeDeps.UserName}");
    }
}
```

This feels like it requires a factory to create but then is it best to request the `HttpClient` and `Logger` in the factory method or declare it as a dependency of the factory? If the latter, I presume the factory would have to be registered as a transient or as a scoped resource since registering it as a singleton would result in a captive dependency (I think).

Any suggestions on redesigns are also welcome if this is a symptom of a poor design. I'd love to implement Mark Seeman's [Pure DI](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/) to get some more assistance from the compiler but I don't know if that's possible in Azure functions.

Comment: You might want to read [Dependency Injection Code Smell: Injecting runtime data into components](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/runtime-data).

Comment: @Steven I've read that but I think I lack the understanding to implement it in my application. The adapter's shown at the end of the article are "part of the composition root" because they're just accessing static values like DateTime.Now or HttpContext.Current but in my app, a request is needed first before the runtime values are generated so I'm not sure how I could add these adapters to the composition root. I also don't quite understand the difference in those implementations of the runtime data vs a factory. The callers look like they're using them pretty similarly to factories.

Comment: I'll try to answer the question with your specific context in mind, but in order to do so, I need more information. Can you describe what `RuntimeDeps` are for values. You say they come from the request. But are they coming from a session or cookie perhaps? Or is it something that is only sent with specific requests? Please elaborate on this, because the answer to your question is highly dependent on what role they play in the application.

Comment: @Steven, sure (and thanks!).

The runtime deps are sent with the request. This component is in my app's backend, which runs in Azure functions using the durable task extension. Users initiate a process in the frontend which then generates an ID for that process and sends it to the backend - this is one of the runtime deps. The other is created once the topmost orchestrator function starts executing. The orchestrator has its own ID that's useful in logs. These two are passed into a component calling an external API and it's this component I want to wire up into my functions with DI

Comment: @Steven there are other runtime dependencies too. The downstream API is a service the users control and my app interacts with on their behalf (or the behalf of another account they provide). One of the runtime dependencies is the specific instance of this downstream service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of requiring runtime data during the construction of a component, it's better to let runtime data flow through method calls on an initialized object graph by either:

1. passing runtime data through method calls of the API or
2. retrieving runtime data from specific abstractions that allow resolving runtime data.

I formalized this in 2015 in [this blog post](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/runtime-data/), which I referred to in the comments.

After reading your additional comments, I came to the conclusion that in your case option 2 is most suited, as the data you are sending is likely an implementation detail to the component, and should not be part of the public API.

In that case, you can redesign your component as follows:

```cs
public class Dependency : IDependency
{
    public Dependency(
        ILogger<Dependency> logger,
        HttpClient httpClient,
        IRuntimeDepsProvider provider) ...

    public Result DoStuff()
    {
        // use Http client to talk to external API
        // something fails so log the failure and some helpful info
        logger.log($"{provider.InstanceId} failed. " +
            $"Initiated by {provider.UserName}");
    }
}
```

`IRuntimeDepsProvider` is an abstraction that hides the retrieval and storage of runtime data. This gives you the ability to postpone the decision to either use a [Closure Composition Model](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/ccm/) or an [Ambient Composition Model](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/acm/) until the [Last Responsible Moment](https://1library.net/article/the-last-responsible-moment-lean-software-development.yr8gro7z).

Using the `IRuntimeDepsProvider` abstraction, you can chose to set the incoming runtime values *after* the object graph is constructed. For instance:

```cs
public class MyFunction
{
    // Notice the different abstraction here
    public MyFunction(
        IRuntimeDepsInitializer initializer,
        IHandler<Something> handler) ...

    public void TheFunction(Guid instanceId, string userName, Something cmd)
    {
        // Setting the runtime data *after* the object graph is constructed,
        initializer.SetData(instanceId, userName);

        // but before the graph's public methods are invoked.
        handler.Handle(cmd);
    }
}
```

Here, a second abstraction is introduced, namely `IRuntimeDepsInitializer`. Now you can have one class implementing both interfaces:

```cs
public class RuntimeDepsStorage : IRuntimeDepsInitializer, IRuntimeDepsProvider
{
    public Guid InstanceId { get; private set; }
    public string UserName { get; private set; }

    public void SetData(Guid id, string name)
    {
        InstanceId = id;
        UserName = name;
    }
}
```

> TIP: Instead of using two interfaces, you can also use only `IRuntimeDepsProvider` and let `MyFunction` depend on the concrete `RuntimeDepsStorage`. Which solution is best depends on the context.

Now the main trick here is to make sure that `RuntimeDepsStorage` becomes a `Scoped` dependency, because you want to reuse it throughout a request, but not shared by multiple requests.

When applying Pure DI, this would look like this:

```
var storage = new RuntimeDepsStorage();

new MyFuncion(
    initializer: storage,
    handler: new SomethingHandler(
        stuffDoer: new Dependency(
            httpClient: client, // Did you notice this is a runtime dep as well?
            logger: new Logger<Dependency>(),
            provider: storage)))
```

If, on the other hand, you would be using MS.DI as your DI Container, registration would be similar to the following:

```cs
services.AddScoped(_ => new RuntimeDepsStorage());
services.AddScoped<IRuntimeDepsProvider>(
    c => c.GetRequiredService<RuntimeDepsStorage>());
services.AddScoped<IRuntimeDepsInitializer>(
    c => c.GetRequiredService<RuntimeDepsStorage>());
// etc, your usual registrations here
```

Comment: I've read this a few times and I think I'm starting to grok it but let me play it back to see if I'm on the right track:

Instead of depending on the runtime dependencies during construction of the `Dependency` type, we've wired up the type so it depends on an abstraction of the runtime dependencies so that at runtime, the function initializes the properties on the concrete provider of the runtime dependencies and since the DI system used the same instance of the `RuntimeDepsStorage` type, the function is updating the same object that its dependency needs?

Comment: I've also got a follow on question: doesn't this then add some temporal coupling in the function where a developer needs to remember to call the SetData method before using the Dependency or else they'll run into runtime exceptions?

Comment: To respond to your first comment: yes, you understanding is correct.

Comment: Yes, this method causes temporal coupling. This is something I mention in the blog posts on Composition Models as well. Temporal Coupling can only be prevented in certain cases and only when using Pure DI (as I mention in my series), but you likely won't be able to achieve this in Azure Functions. Still, this unfortunate temporal coupling is better than the alternative: injecting runtime data into components during construction.

Answer (score 2):

A transient factory with the transient dependencies injected into the constructor and the runtime dependencies as parameters of the Create method will work fine.

DI is baked into the Azure Functions library in the sense that parameters are injected into the trigger methods, but beyond these you should be able to use Pure DI to manage your own dependencies by calling into some composition root helper class from the trigger function which knows how to build your dependency graph in a pure manner.

Comment: I presume that a transient factory with scoped dependencies would also be fine given the DI system will just inject the same instances of those dependencies into the new instances of the factory if they're within the same scope, right? My challenge in understanding is that the dependencies are all scoped to the request (like HttpClient) and I'd like to avoid captive dependencies while still using them correctly.

Comment: Yes, the dependencies can have a longer lifetime than the factory